# ask for permissions in facebook c# sdk

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have followed [this](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website&referringTitle=Documentation) simple tutorial. But how can I ask for friends_photos permission?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial in question is very basic. You need to add a references to the Facebook Web MVC C# SDK dlls. The easiest way to do this is using NuGet. To add the reference, right click on “References”, and then click “Add Library Package  Reference…”. Do a search for FacebookWebMVC and install it.

In the controller you will need to add an attribute the the page action, this will trigger the permission to access "friends_photos".

```
[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "friends_photos")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View();
}
```